# How to create regex pattern for validating editext in android?

Tags: java, android, regex

am create reg-ex for validating edit text field.am not able to validate correctly.

```
my condition to validate is 
Example (h2/g2)
At-least have a one numerical value
slash also allowed but only one,after the "/" must have one numerical value.
alphabets also allowed
```

How to create reg-ex for this condition.Can any one know please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide more examples of what's valid and what's not or a formal description. This will help to get a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this: `(\w*/)?\w*\d\w*`

Remember that in Java you have to duplicate backslashes `\\`.

Adding more examples of valid and invalid texts would help.

**Edit:**

Answering you comment. Yes, it does:

```
String value = "h2/g2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w*/)?\\w*\\d\\w*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
Log.i("tag", "matches? " + m.matches());
```

prints:

```
I/tag(12642): matches? true
```

Comment: @Yugesh It does. More examples?

Comment: How to include # - like slash in that pattern.

Comment: @Yugesh (\w*[-/#])?\w*\d\w* Next time try to make your question specific and show all your examples to have a full answer.